# cant get Model in aspx from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get get model in aspx page. How can i get it. is anything i have to do in config file? PLease help  me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs" 
 Inherits="IBATechnologies.IBA.Main.Views.Report" %>
 <%@ page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <script runat="server">
    Model // here i cant find Model "the name Model is not in current 
   context"
    </script>

</head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure but you can use DynamicViewPage instead ViewPage.

may be this link will help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views

Comment: thank you @Andrew i add system.web.mvc to aspx page that solve my issue